# Dual boot mechanism did not finish installing

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation

Win7 + Lubuntu 16.04 (via USB Memory stick) did not finish installing and when rebooted: boots only into Ubuntu.  As expected, Lubuntu was installed in the second HDD partition: Windows partition shrunk to 40GB and was unformatted for Lubuntu.

This is the screenshot of where installation froze:
[image]

Is it possible to command the USB install to continue setting up and finish the dual boot mecahnism?

Comment: The screenshot says it's stuck at initramfs, not at installing Grub. I don't understand why bring LILO into play which is not the default bootloader for these installation media AFAIK. The procedure to install Grub after the installation has been described in http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/40581, you should also run `update-initramfs -u` in addition to update-grub, because my guess is that it got stuck at creating the initrd. This is all guesswork though, you should provide [installation logs](http://askubuntu.com/tags/ubiquity/info) if you expect accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

First you must update the `initramfs`. Then you need to reinstall `grub` and update it. 
Here are the steps.

1. Once you have logged in Lubuntu, open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
2. First log into root shell using `sudo -s`.
3. Run `update-initramfs -u` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. After the execution of the command has completed run `grub-install /dev/sdX` where `sdX` is your HDD. If the OS is installed on internal HDD, then replace `sdX` by `sda`. The command would then look like `grub-install /dev/sda`.
5. After the grub has installed, run `update-grub`.
6. After the command has finished executing log out of the root shell by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.
7. Now close the terminal and reboot the system.

You will now have the option to boot into either OSes.

Comment: @cedael: Thank you for the well written suggestion: the instructions were followed and attempts to reboot do not present the menu \ options for OS.  Please revise answer with any additional steps